# Me sale el error 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.' en xamarin forms, (la fecha si cumple el formato)

Tags: c#, xamarin, datetime, xamarin.forms

Actualmente quier comparar dos fecha, una fecha se obtiene con `Datetime.Now` y la otra proviene de un servicio `REST` y viene en formato `string` y quiero convertirla en Fecha dentro de C# para poder hacer una comparacion de fechas, estoy usando `Xamarin.Forms`:

Código C#:

```
DateTime fechaAVencer = DateTime.ParseExact(lstPuntos[3], "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

La entrada de `lstPuntos[3]` viene de la siguiente forma  `08/18/2020 7:51:43 p. m.` y el error que me sale es el siguiente:

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid
> DateTime.'

Tambien intente anexandole la siguiente opcion al DateTime.parseExact:

```
DateTime fechaAVencer = DateTime.ParseExact(lstPuntos[3], "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pude notar 2 problemas:

1. El dato que contiene `lstPuntos[3]`, tiene la hora en formato de 12 horas y para estos casos se debe utilizar la `h` *(minúscula)*. [ver documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#lowercase-hour-h-format-specifier)
2. El otro problema está relacionado con `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

   - Cuando se utiliza `tt` para especificar que la cadena a convertir contiene `AM/PM`, el formato es tomado de las propiedades [AMDesignator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.amdesignator?view=netcore-3.1) o [PMDesignator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.pmdesignator?view=netcore-3.1) de la cultura indicada [ver más](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#tSpecifier).
   - En `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` los valores esperados son AM y PM *(sin puntos ni espacios y da igual si son mayúscula o minúscula)*

Luego de hacer algunas pruebas, encontré que la siguiente combinación funciona con el dato `08/18/2020 7:51:43 p. m.`

- `MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt` el único cambio aquí es que la `h` va en minúscula.
- `new CultureInfo("es-MX")` elegí México por la información en tu perfil.

Tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
DateTime fechaAVencer = DateTime.ParseExact(lstPuntos[3], "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", new CultureInfo("es-MX"));
```

#### Recomendaciones

Considera utilizar [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netcore-3.1) para evitar la excepción en los casos en que la conversión no pueda realizarse.

```
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(lstPuntos[3], "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", new CultureInfo("es-MX"), DateTimeStyles.None, out fechaAVencer))
{
    // aquí la conversión fue exitosa y el resultado está en la variable fechaAVencer
}
else
{
    // aquí la conversión falló
}
```

En caso de que tengas control sobre el servicio REST de donde obtienes la fecha, considera guardarla en un formato de 24 horas `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`, así evitas el `AM/PM` y podrás usar `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`